# VBA querying SSAS model - peer prematurely closed connection

Tags: sql-server, vba, ssas

I have an SSAS model on a SQL Server that I am trying to query from VBA.  This was working fine a few days ago, however the admin password on the remote machine changed recently.  Now I am getting error:  "Runtime error -2147467259 (80004005) The peer prematurely closed the connection".

I've tried rebuilding and redeploying my SSAS model to no avail.  Any thoughts as to why I'm getting this error and how to resolve it?

Thanks!

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim oSht As Worksheet
Dim sql As String
Set oSht = Worksheets("modelcq")
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
oConn.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=dc2k8housql;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=NVO_CQ_V1;"
oConn.Open 'error occurs here!
Debug.Print oConn.State
```

Answer (score 0):

I specified the Username and password for the SSAS account on the SQL box and that worked.